# Visual studio 2015.Ошибка при установке

Tags: установка, visual-studio-2015

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить это?После обновления VS2015 все сломалось.

Comment: а вы не пробовали этот компонент отдельно от студии установить?

Comment: Да,то же самое.